# read dir not in the file system order

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code :

```
 if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    print_r(" ".$file. " ");
                    $data = array(
                        'emplacement' => 'uploads/slidesFiles/'.$file
                    );
                    $jpgId = $CI->dataaccess::InsertJpg($data);
                    $data = array(
                        'idSlideZip' => $zipId,
                        'idSlideJpg' =>$jpgId
                    );
                    $CI->dataaccess::InsertJpgToSlide($data);
                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
```

My folder :

[image: folder order]

But when I am using the read dir function to loop into my folder, I dont have the expected order wich is the next :

[image: read dir order]

I tried to reorder with the sort function but that is not the result expected.

[image: sort order]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Looks like you're suffering from *lexicographic* sorting.

What you need is [natsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

**Alphabetical:**

```
1, 10, 2, 3
```

**Natsort:**

```
1, 2, 3, 10
```

The reason for this is because the elements in your array are treated as strings, so every character in the string is treated as a character and not an integer.

[Further reading.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/why-do-some-sorting-methods-sort-by-1-10-2-3)

Comment: Ty Couldn't see this function in this doc : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Comment: Just as a general rule it's always best to refer to [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/) when looking at functions, W3Schools is notoriously unreliable.